# Magento 2 Add 'Remove out of stock' filter in category page and search results page

Tags: collection, filter, magento-2.1.7

I have to add 'Remove out of stock' filter on the category page and search results page.

By default i m displaying all products which is in stock or out of stock.

Any suggestions please? i m not getting proper solution and m new with magento 2.